# Prestashop : Get products by features

Tags: module, prestashop, product

In my module on Prestashop I need to display list of products but I need to get them by features, for example : i need to get all products where the id feature 1 has the id value 2.

Is this function exist in Prestashop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be your solution:

```
$featuresObj = new Product($product['id_product']);
$features = $featuresObj->getFrontFeatures($this->context->language->id);

foreach($features as $feature)
{
    var_dump($feature);
}
```